# Are there objects that can't be elements of sets, or be sets themselves?

Tags: set-theory

I heard of urelements, which don't contain elements; I've also heard of proper classes which can't be elements of sets, has anyone ever discussed objects that can't be elements in a set or be themselves sets?

Comment: In most set theories in which proper classes exist, proper classes satisfy your criterion: they are not sets, and they cannot be elements of sets.

Comment: I'm having a hard time conceiving of something that I can't put into an imaginary box other than the paradoxical set that contains itself. I don't even really consider proper classes to be distinct, I just think of them as a hierarchy of sets to avoid Russell's paradox.

Comment: @CyclotomicField There is nothing paradoxical about a set that contains itself. It's true that ZFC set theory rules out such sets by the axiom of foundation / regularity. But we can replace the axiom of foundation with an alternative "anti-foundation" axiom and arrive at a theory which proves there is a set which contains itself - and we can prove that the new theory is consistent if ZFC is consistent. Note that the set which contains itself *can* be put into an imaginary box: it's already in an imaginary box, namely itself!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I thought the paradox had to do with the specific set that was defined to contain all sets that do not contain themselves.

Comment: @PaulAsh Correct! What's paradoxical is the set of all sets that do not contain themselves. The concept of a set containing itself is not paradoxical on its own.

Comment: @AlexKruckman True, but I do think I worded the question poorly, cause classes have members, and aren't considered sets to avoid any paradoxes, so I guess I'm asking if there's any object that has been discussed under any axioms, which can't be inside of a collection of objects nor have any objects in it

Answer (score 4):

In mathematics we do not consider questions like "are there objects that are XYZ?", which is a rather philosophical question. In mathematics we consider questions like "are there objects that are XYZ under ABC axioms?". Everything in maths is relative to some axiomatic theory.

In particular the answer to this question depends on the theory you consider. The [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (ZF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) which is widely regarded as the standard set theory does not consider anything other than sets and relations between them. And so within this theory urelements and proper classes are not defined, are meaningless. Even when you consider "collection of all sets", in ZF we can only deduce that it is not a set. Such thing doesn't exist within the theory. That's all.

But there are other theories that do consider such objects. For example ZF can be extended to [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) which does deal with [proper classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) (which is a "collection" that is too big to fit in any set) formally.

A theory that deals with [urelements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) (which are things that can be elements of set, but are not sets themselves) is for example [Kripke–Platek set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory_with_urelements), but honestly, this is some exotic maths. Until today I didn't even hear about such theory...

Also the original ZF (which is not the same as the current one) did consider urelements. But people quickly realized that this concept is superfluous and it was removed from it. I think that urelements are very rarely considered. Unlike proper classes, which are widely used for example within [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory).

Ultimately in maths everything is about sets or relations between them. You can of course consider whatever you want, but in practice a theory that is unrelated to sets at all will likely not be of much use. In particular that's why ZF is so widely accepted.